# Multidimensional slicing in raw Python

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have an array defined as

```
[
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
```

and I wanted to get a vertical slice, returning `[2, 5, 8]`.  Is there any way to do this with slicing syntax in straight Python?  When I try to look up multidimensional slicing, the only results I tend to see are all talking about numpy, and using the syntax discussed there gives errors in raw Python.

Comment: `[inner[1] for inner in outer]`?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of a direct way to get a vertical slice and this is probably more expensive than the list comprehension answer but still

```
z = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
list(zip(*z)[1])
[2, 5, 8]
```

Or this may be slightly less expensive

```
from itertools import izip, islice
list(*islice(izip(*z), 1, 2))
[2, 5, 8]
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure. You could generally use a for loop. Or simply you could code like:

```
>>> test = [
  [1, 2, 3],
  [4, 5, 6],
  [7, 8, 9]
]
>>> [row[1] for row in test]
[2, 5, 8]
```

This piece of code will generate a new list for a vertical slice. If you really need a slice operation, the following code would be useful:

```
>>> [item for sublist in test for item in sublist][1::len(test[0])]
[2, 5, 8]
```

Comment: I know I could use a loop, but is there any way to do it with a slice expression?

Comment: What do you mean for "slice expression"?

Comment: If you just need one element in each row, why do you need a slice operation?

Comment: @MasonWheeler list comprehension is not any more of a loop then slicing.